# Why does Windows Search "Indexing Options" select the wrong drive if it's cloned?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, clone, windows-search, search-indexing

I cloned a Windows 10 HDD to a Samsung SSD using "Samsung Data Migration Software", then installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 on the SSD.  The SSD is now `C:` and the HDD is `D:`.

When in Control Panel > Indexing Options > Modify, any folder I add for `C:\` actually selects `D:\`.  For example, I'll select `C:\Windows` > OK > then Modify again and it's `D:\Windows` that's selected; or if I select a folder that doesn't exist in `D:`, such as `C:\util`, it adds an entry like `D:\util\ (unavailable)`.

Something is confusing Windows Search and Indexing Options due to the cloned drives. When looking in the registry, I can see entries such as:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\DefaultRules\12
```

- **`REG_SZ`** 
   Name: `URL` 
   Data: `file:///C:\\[9a6b2440-0cb7-4d60-a957-7a1682cf61c4]\\WINDOWS\\`

It might be the GUID after `C:\\` that's confusing Indexing Options, but this GUID appears nowhere else in the registry other than under `Windows Search`. 
It's not the volume's unique identifier that can be seen using `Mountvol`, and it's not the GPT identifier (or the partition type) that can be seen using `DiskPart`.

Note: others have experienced the same issue (in Windows 8 as well), see:

- [Issue with Indexing in Windows confusing C disk with D disk - need to change SID](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5381142e-12aa-47da-bae2-18e6d35f414f/issue-with-indexing-in-windows-confusing-c-disk-with-d-disk-need-to-change-sid?forum=w8itproinstall)
- [Why does the Search Indexer in Windows 10 insist on indexing the wrong partition?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd2b31ea-4bf4-4271-886c-47131cc1b6c8/why-does-the-search-indexer-in-windows-10-insist-on-indexing-the-wrong-partition?forum=win10itprogeneral)
- [I have a problem with Windows 10 Search Indexing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba7da25d-5754-42ee-a55e-c4b38d27f2fd/i-have-a-problem-with-windows-10-search-indexing?forum=win10itprogeneral)
- [Windows 10 indexing selects wrong drive](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/windows-10-indexing-selects-wrong-drive/685ec87b-e7f3-454b-89c9-c485b94bb69d)
- [Windows 10 indexing problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-indexing-problem/6aea5879-6d13-4a67-b30a-ab255a92ee0c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I can reproduce your problem:

[image]

The problem is caused by the system file `\System Volume Information\IndexerVolumeGuid` in each of the cloned volumes. Apparently you are right about the fact that the system is confused by the GUID(s) you see in those the registry entries under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\*`, and this file should be the provider of the GUID(s).

Since the volumes are cloned, this particular file is identical among each of them just like other files. And it will NOT get "updated" (i.e. regenerated to avoid conflicts) when the volumes are mounted, just like the volume serial:

[image]

However, apparently this file is safe to be deleted, and once the volume is mounted again, a new one will be generated; the problem will be gone once ALL the volumes that owned a duplicated GUID are remounted with unique GUIDs (so a reboot may be necessary if it involves the current system volume):

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, I am not sure if there's a convenient/safe way to delete it under Windows:

[image]

Comment: Impressive. How did you figure this out?

Comment: I have been testing and fliping through information about NTFS (metadata, metafile...), and couldn't find anything really seems like it. And then I thought I should test with FAT32 and see if things behave differently and they didn't. So I figure this is probably related to some hidden system file, which could be found on both types of filesystems.

Comment: Ok, will verify that's the case when I get back to my PC so I can accept your answer. So FAT32 doesn't have an equivalent to NTFS's "volume unique identifier"? It still seems like a design flaw - ie, it should use the NTFS feature when it's there, otherwise fail back to a hidden system file GUID. Btw deleting it seems do-able by taking ownership and changing security permissions.

Comment: `volume unique id` (`mountvol  X: /L`) has nothing to do with the filesystem, but only the partition (table). For GPT disk, Windows use the `unique partition GUID` as the `volume unique id`. For MBR disk, it make use of the disk identifier (`uniqueid` in `diskpart`) and the starting position of the partition to form the `volume unique id`. Both FAT32 and NTFS have `volume serial`; it's just the one of NTFS is technically longer (`fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo X:`, but if you check with `dir X:` only part of the NTFS serial is shown, probably for compatibility with the shorter FAT32 serial).

Comment: Somehow Microsoft prefer not to use any of the serial / IDs for its indexer, but randomly generate another one and store it in a hidden system file (if not already exists) when the volume is mounted. I am not sure if it can be called a design flaw though. It's just Microsoft doesn't seem to consider "cloning" an orthodox thing to do. (But well, at least Windows regenerates those GUIDs on the partition table for you.)

Comment: I can see a number of ways Microsoft could handle this better. (1) Indexing Options/Windows Search to give a decent error and link to solutions when detecting duplicate IDs. (2) Use `volume unique id` instead of `IndexerVolumeGuid`, since as you said this is regenerated correctly when it's a duplicate (3) Regenerate `IndexerVolumeGuid` just like `volume unique id` is regenerated when it's duplicate. You're right that cloning isn't common, but selecting D:\ when I chose C:\ is just a bug, duplicate IDs or not.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I've verified that both C: and D: have the same `IndexerVolumeGuid`

Comment: I was able to delete IndexerVolumeGuid from an admin command prompt after removing the readonly attribute from System Volume Information and its children. Rebooted afterwards, Windows assigned a new GUID, and indexing started working again.

Comment: This is great. Just a note. Removing `IndexerVolumeGuid` is trivial if you have Cygwin installed. Just start an administrative Cygwin window and do `rm '/cygdrive/c/System Volume Information/IndexerVolumeGuid'` and reboot. Remember to do this for all cloned partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Just registered to say thanks for this, has been causing me problems for 18 months since I cloned a windows system drive onto an nvme using xxclone and kept the old drive around (without formatting) for data and backup purposes.

I was able to delete the GUID file from the old drive just by running cmd as Administrator, and I rebooted (may not have been necessary) - had to do a little clean up on the indexing folder options but once I'd completed that, the indexer started working again. Awesome.

Comment: How did you delete the GUID from Windows cmd?  What command did you use?  The accepted answer says they don't know how and your's says that you were able to do it by running cmd as Administrator...  What command did you use exactly?

Comment: Download `sysinternals` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) and run `psexec -s cmd.exe` from an Administrator command prompt, which will open another command prompt with `SYSTEM` account privileges.

Comment: Sorry completely missed this question (came back here because I'm cloning to another NVME drive and now got the fun of GPT boot managers but anyway...) for the record I simply used the command line
"del filename"
to delete the file! I didn't need to be logged in with the system account but that would work too as per zencraft's comment.