# Windows search not finding files on one drive - Drive missing from indexer search roots

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

<sub>*Note: I have posted the same question a while ago on [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/drive-missing-from-indexer-search-roots/c233ed97-4b48-489c-b936-21c6b6da31b4), where I got no reply so far*</sub>

While trying to investigate issues with files not being found by the search indexer, I have noticed that there seems to be an issue with a drive missing from the search roots. Some details that might be important:

- The computer has three internal drives:

  - OS Drive C:, SSD, all the usual system partitions
  - Data drive E:, HDD, two partitions (the other one doesn't need to be indexed)
  - Data drive D:, Storage space, one partition
- In `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\SearchRoots`, the following entries are listed (note how the GUIDs seem to be the same for the `D` and `E` drives):

  ```
  defaultroot://{S-1-5-21-740414505-3273780380-2204535043-1001}/
  file:///C:\[d2ba34b2-ebef-456a-a0d6-8da93b88df93]\
  file:///D:\[3c8e34ff-7776-47f8-abaf-4334ed09d427]\
  file:///E:\[3c8e34ff-7776-47f8-abaf-4334ed09d427]\
  winrt://{S-1-5-21-740414505-3273780380-2204535043-1001}/
  ```
- The indexer diagnostics tool lists `file:///C:\` and `file:///E:\` under "Search roots", which contradicts the registry key
- Under "What is being indexed?", the tool lists only paths starting with `C:\` and `E:\`, where the paths starting with `E:\` are on `D:\` in reality. The same list for excluded paths appears in the Settings app under "Searching Windows"
- The "Indexing options" dialog shows both folders on  `D:\` and `E:\` as being indexed (when clicking on "Modify"). In the "Index these locations" view, no location from `E:\` is actually listed
- The search mode is set to "Classic"
- I have tried to reset the search index several times already, both via "Rebuild index" and by setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\SetupCompletedSuccessfully` to `0`

What is going on here? Why is the Indexer diagnostics tool confusing `D:\` and `E:\`? Why are locations from `E:\` not appearing in the list of locations to index? Is there any way to add a drive to the search roots/let the indexer recreate them entirely?

Please let me know if any additional information is required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution to this problem: This solution is based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1053452/why-does-windows-search-indexing-options-select-the-wrong-drive-if-its-cloned), with some more details on how to actually fix the issue.

## The cause

One of the drives was created as a clone from the other one at some point. This results in identical GUIDs for the two drives, at least as far as the indexer is concerned (these are *not* the standard partition GUIDs or similar). The GUID is stored in `*:\System Volume Information\IndexerVolumeGuid`, so it's quite straightforward to reset it apart from the permission issues.

## The solution

This is what I did to solve the issue:

- Stop the `Windows Search` service, and set the start type to `Disabled`
- Open `regedit.exe`

  - Set the value `SetupCompletedSuccessfully` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\` to `0`
  - Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\SearchRoots`, and delete all keys corresponding to the colliding drives
- Download [`psexec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), and run the command `psexec -sid cmd` from a command line prompt with administrative privileges

  - The newly launched command line has system privileges, so be careful!
  - Navigate to the first colliding drive by typing `D:` (where `D` is the letter of the drive)
  - Go to the `System Volume Information` folder by typing `cd "System Volume Information"`
  - Delete the GUID file by typing `del IndexerVolumeGuid`
  - Repeat these steps for all colliding drives
- Set the start type of the `Windows Search` service back to `Automatic` and start the service again.
- The search index should now be rebuilding, this time without any issues. Note that all settings for included/excluded folders have been deleted, so you probably have to reselect them via the `Indexing Options` settings panel by pressing `Modify`